# Appium GUI-test for WPF, how to get it working on Azure?

Tags: wpf, azure, appium

I have 2 simple GUI-test on a WPF application. They work alright from VisualStudio.

Now I am trying to also do that in my Azure pipeline. Ik keep on bumping against the same error right at the start:
"OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters"

Basically I am working along this line: [WinAppDriver in CI with Azure Pipelines](https://github.com/microsoft/WinAppDriver/blob/master/Docs/CI_AzureDevOps.md). One difference with the example is that I have put my tests in my build pipeline instead of my release pipeline. As far as I can determine that should not be the cause of my problem, using the same Windows-2019 agent.

This is how the pipeline looks like, up to the tests:

[image: Pipeline]

In the past I have had problems from VisualStudio similar to those decribed here, but I have left those behind. [FindElementByName - Element couldn't be located](https://github.com/Microsoft/WinAppDriver/issues/370)

Nevertheless I have tried to improve on these aspects by using DefaultWait. It works fine from VisualStudio but has not helped me on Azure.

I read a couple of times about an 'interactive mode' for the agent. But I don't see anything about that in the guideline, and it seems to apply to self hosted agents. I also don't see any configuration option on the standard agent. So I am confused about that.

I am lost here.

Could someone tell me what I am missing?

It would be much appreciated, I have been spending quite some time on this already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This took me a while to find the necessary information and piece together the solution, which turned out to work.

The key thing is using an interactive agent, which has to be self hosted. Key instruction for me was following [Self-hosted Windows agents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows). This resulted in installing an environment on my own hardware, and to be pretty simple and straight forward.

This implies one has to startup this environment with Powershell, and probably guard the graphical test as it executes. For an one man team as mine that is no problem, for a larger team this may be an issue.

An additional advantage is that the entire building and execution environment is now under one's own control for overview and inspection.

It's funny to push a commit and see the pipeline progress on Azure, plus starting up the graphical test on my own hardware.

Comment: *"This implies one has to startup this environment with Powershell"* – I've done something similar (on a VM) with the GitLab runner and ended up running a Powershell script scheduled after boot. After it was configured it required no more interaction to run our UI-Tests